# How to compare array of number with string of number?

Tags: php, laravel

i make advance search, one of my inputs is checkbox.
When click submit, return value of checkbox in array, for example [1,2,3,4]
I want to compare this array with column of table that type is string, for example this column value is 1,2 for one record and 2,5 or 3,6 or 1,2,3 for other record.
My question is How can return record with this attribute?
In this example goal is return records that exist one of element of array in string column.

Comment: You want to check if an array element exists in a string?

Comment: yes, and return records of table whit this attribute.

Comment: You might want to rethink your column here.  Storing multiple values in a single column is the first sign you've broken database normalization.

Comment: wath's your idea for save multiple values in table?

Comment: Did you try? Do you have code?

Comment: A comma separated list of values in a column is literally the first example of [violating 1st Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form#Designs_that_violate_1NF)

Comment: Dear bas, yes i try, and my code for return record is $places->whereIn('envch', $nvch); $envch is my array [1,2]. but this code not return record because my column with name 'envch' values can be string ,2,5 or 1,3,4 or ... . How to compare those?

Comment: you can't search 1 within ,2,5 or in 1,3,4 doing laravel. Try ->orWhere('envch', 'like', )

Comment: Why? How can do it?

Comment: Because you are looking for 1 in 1,3,4 returns null If the column has 1 as string than it returns. You have to work with separated tables where 1,3,4 are separated in 3 rows. Ans use eloquent to join them.

Comment: Could serialized array or unserialized envch column for compare values and use whereIn method in laravel?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strchr if you want to sesarch on string check code bellow :

```
$array=array(1,2,3,4);

$string="test1test4tset3";
foreach($array as $key)
{
    if(strchr($string,$key))
        print $key.' exist';


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will fulfill your request.

```
//iterate through your table and let's assume $row is your currently row
foreach ($array as &$value) 
    if (strpos($row["string"], $value) !== false) 
       foreach($row as &$rowValue)
          echo $rowValue."\n";
```